# Leaking wall-mounted toilet (Duravit)

Tags: plumbing, toilet, leak

I have a Duravit Model-No. 253509 wall-mounted toilet that is leaking in a minor way around the wall. Please see below for some photos and details.

Please let me know if you have ideas on the source of the issue and potential solutions. Could this be from the in-wall tank, or does it have something to do with the toilet-wall mount?

[image]

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/G6jmR.jpg)
[image]

[image]

Comment: why would you ask us to guess what the problem might be? ... after all, it would only be a guess ... remove the toilet from the wall and investigate the source of the leak

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You’re going to need to pull the bowl off the carrier/wall.  Based on the fact the leak appears to be towards the top of the bowl, I’d check the filler tube/inlet.  Make sure it’s cut to the correct length and make sure the gasket is greased so it goes in straight and smooth.  I seriously doubt it’s the carrier.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I have found the issue and it wasn't something I expected. It turned out to be due to a weak wall surface on which the toilet was mounted. The instructions say it should be mounted on cement board or some other hard material, but they used regular blue board. Over many years, flex developed and wore away the edge of the filler tube, which leaked a small amount of water, especially if the person is sitting on the toilet while flushing.

The solution was to replace the wall with cement board and a 1/8 HDF layer mounted to the studs. So far, so good.